# Problem with images when closing the Tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title('Кликер')
full_screen = 0
root.geometry('1920x1080')

stop = 0


def clock():
    global stop
    if stop == 0:
        ClockGif = PhotoImage(file='Часы\Часы0.png')
        ClockLabel = Label(root, image=ClockGif, bd=0)
        ClockLabel.place(x=10, y=10)
        root.after(47900, clocks)
        root.update
        for i in range(958):
            root.after(50)
            root.update()
            ClockGif['file'] = 'Часы\Часы' +str(i) + '.png'
    else:
        pass


def clocks():
    global stop
    if stop == 0:
        clock()
    else:
        pass


def stoper():
    global stop
    stop = 1

root.after(1000, stoper)
root.update
clock()

root.mainloop()
```

Hello, when closing the Tkinter window, an error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python project/python project/GeekBrains/game/Игра/test.py", line 42, in <module>
    clock()
  File "G:/Python project/python project/GeekBrains/game/Игра/test.py", line 23, in clock
    ClockGif['file'] = 'Часы\Часы' +str(i) + '.png'
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4020, in __setitem__
    self.tk.call(self.name, 'configure', '-'+key, value)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "pyimage1"
```

Process finished with exit code 1

I think the error is due to this part of the code, what could be the problem?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do

Comment: I'm trying to make an animation of the movement of the clock

Comment: I'm not sure why your approach is such, try: `ClockGif['image'] = 'Часы\Часы' +str(i) + '.png'`. Not to mention you need `global clockGif` inside function too.

Comment: May I know if the error shows up when you close the window during execution or after the execution is complete, because if you close the window while the images are being changed, then it is possible that when `root.update()` is called after the interval, the root no longer exists and neither does its child widgets, and the error comes up because the image can't be associated with them.

Comment: @AST Unfortunately, I can't track when the picture changes. I see one solution to the problem. You can make a wait until the loop ends. Only I don't quite understand how to implement it

Comment: If you wait until the cycle ends, and do not start it again, the program closes without problems

Comment: One way could be to use use the `try:` (the code under the loop in `clock`)  `except: pass`  that way the error would be handled and it won't be seen, since the program automatically stops after that error (because it has got `root` to update), it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @AST with try, I was able to solve the problem. But now I have a new one.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python project/python project/GeekBrains/game/Игра/game.py", line 1179, in <module>
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", save)
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2188, in wm_protocol
    return self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "wm" command: application has been destroyed

Comment: @AST Thank you very much, I really managed to solve this problem

Comment: Glad to be of help, just to keep things organized I would suggest you to comment any answer related queries in the comment section of that specific answer and not under the question. Apart form that if you found my answer helpful enough you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by selecting the tick mark and leave an up vote if deserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think, as you terminate the window, when the scheduled `root.update()` is called or when the image file is being changed in `ClockGif` its parent `root` no longer exists and hence the association can not take place, so is the error. Out of multiple possible ways to solve this, here are some of my solutions:

- Using a flag that indicates that the window has been destroyed

Add this to the main code

```
def on_close():
    global win_state
    win_state=False
    root.destroy()

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_close)
win_state=True
```

Make changes to the `clock` function

```
def clock():
    global stop, win_state
    if stop == 0:
        ClockGif = PhotoImage(file='Часы\Часы0.png')
        ClockLabel = Label(root, image=ClockGif, bd=0)
        ClockLabel.place(x=10, y=10)
        root.after(47900, clocks)
        root.update
        for i in range(958):
            if win_state:
                root.after(50)
                root.update()
                ClockGif['file'] = 'Часы\Часы' +str(i) + '.png'
    else:
        pass
```

- Handle the error silently by making the following change in the `clock` function

```py
try:
    root.after(50)
    root.update()
    ClockGif['file'] = 'Часы\Часы' +str(i) + '.png'
except: 
    pass
```